# C#: Shorten Code (Nullable Object, Return Property or String.Empty)

Tags: c#

I wondered if anybody can come up with a shortened version for this code:

```
MyObject theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
if (theObject == null) return String.Empty;
else return theObject.myProperty;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want an String.Empty to be returned always? You would need to check the value of your property too then.

Comment: The object returned is actually coming from a DB with a constrain requiring the value to not be null so I can omit the check of the property being null or not here. At least it's 2 lines instead of 3 now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MyObject theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
return theObject == null ? String.Empty : theObject.myProperty;
```

Answer (score 4):

In c# 3.0 (framework 3.5) you can write:

```
return (ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject() ?? new MyObject(){ myProperty = ""} ).myProperty;
```

but I will write something more readable like:

return new MyObject(ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject())

and set the property accordly in the constructor

EDIT: 
My memory make me a joke:
?? is not a c# 3.0 feature, but a 2.0 one ;)

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

That code is fine, although I'd recommend the following to improve readability ([and I'm not the only one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)).

```
MyObject theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
if (theObject != null)
    return theObject.myProperty;

return string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
return theObject != null ? theObject.myProperty : String.Empty;

// if you want an String.Empty always to be returned, also when the property is null
return theObject != null ? theObject.myProperty ?? String.Empty : String.Empty;
```

Comment: Even though I don't need it in this case, I'll keep this in mind too. Good thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `?:` operator:

```
MyObject theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
return (theObject == null) ? String.Empty : theObject.myProperty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the ? operator.

```
MyObject theObject = ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject();
return (theObject == null) ? String.Empty : theObject.myProperty;
```

I don't believe you can get this on one line without calling ObjectCollection.GrabAnObject() twice.

Comment: why not? just delete crlf before return! ^^